# In linux ,what's the differences among these bin directories?

Tags: linux

In linux ,what's the differences among these bin directories as following?

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/root/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

- `/bin` and `/sbin` contain essential binaries for non-privileged and privileged users
- `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` contain non-essential binaries (may be unavailable in single-user mode)
- `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` contain binaries specific to the host
- `~/bin` and `/root/bin` contain binaries specific to the user, which is `root` in the latter case

See this Wikipedia article on the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).

Notice that it is conventional. You could build your own Linux distribution, using the Linux kernel, which does not follow these conventions.

Also, IIRC, the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standards define some related conventions.

Some distributions are adopting a variant, e.g. by using `/opt/`